# Apply impulse to a SKSpriteNode from a user swipe

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, skspritenode, uitouch, uievent

Can anyone tell me why when I try to apply an impulse to a node like this it disappears?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first! as UITouch
    startPoint = touch.location(in: view)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    defer {
        startPoint = nil
    }
    guard touches.count == 1, let startPoint = startPoint else {
        return
    }
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let endPoint = touch.location(in: view)
        //Calculate your vector from the delta and what not here
        direction = CGVector(dx: endPoint.x - startPoint.x, dy: endPoint.y - startPoint.y)

        L1Ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: direction.dx.hashValue, dy: direction.dy.hashValue))
        }
}
```

I think it has something to do with the way I am using hashValue. I don't know another way to get the values from the CGVector direction. If I try to use direction itself as the impulse vector it just crashes. Any insight? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked for me when I removed the .hashValue from direction.dx and direction.dy (hash values are used for [comparisons](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/hashable)). Oh and your ball node isn't disappearing. Those hash values are large enough that when you apply them on a ball as a force, the speed of the ball is big enough that by the time the next frame is rendered the ball is off the screen.

Comment: Yes okay, I was misusing hashValue. I edited what I had to this and the sprite moves more realistically. Needed to scale down the vector.
            let impulseDirectionX = (direction.dx / 4)
            let impulseDirectionY = (-direction.dy / 4)
            self.L1Ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: impulseDirectionX, dy: impulseDirectionY))
            self.L1Ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

Comment: That's great. Did I answer your question correctly?